# Debugger for qt in windows?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.6

While I try to debug the application, it pop up the dialog box and shown as below.

[image]

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Have you read http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-debugger-engines.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the Debugging Tools for Windows (the cdb debugger) for QtCreator to use the Microsoft debugger engine for programs built with MSVC.

To use GDB on Windows, you'll need to build the program using MinGW.

Details are available here:  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-debugger-engines.html